# $L:\Bbb{V} \to \Bbb{W}$ is an invertible linear mapping, prove that $\dim\Bbb{V} = \dim\Bbb{W}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $L:\Bbb{V} \to \Bbb{W}$ is an invertible linear mapping, and $\Bbb{V}$,   $\Bbb{W}$ are finite dimensional vector spaces. How would you prove that $\dim\Bbb{V} = \dim\Bbb{W}$?

My attempt for this proof relies on proving that $\Bbb{V}$ and $\Bbb{W}$ are isomorphic. I have proved that $L$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb{V}$ to $\Bbb{W}$. Is this correct?

${}$

Comment: Hint: Take $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ a basis for $\mathbb{V}$ and prove that $Lv_1,Lv_2,...,Lv_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{W}$.

Comment: but would the isomorphism method work as well?

Comment: I'm confused about your idea. The existence of $L$ means (by definition) that $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic. So basically they ask you to prove that isomorphic linear spaces have the same dimension...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rank-nullity theorem says that
$$
\dim\operatorname{im}L+\dim\ker L=\dim V
$$
Since $L$ is invertible, you also have
$$
\dim\operatorname{im}L^{-1}+\dim\ker L^{-1}=\dim W
$$
On the other hand $\ker L=\{0\}$ and $\ker L^{-1}=\{0\}$, so we have
$$
\dim V=\dim\operatorname{im}L\le\dim W=\dim\operatorname{im}L^{-1}\le\dim V
$$

Comment: I'm just having trouble understanding why my method would not work?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt Well, $L$ is an isomorphism by definition. So proving it is not necessary, is it? And then you conclude nothing, do you? Unless you prove that a basis of $V$ is sent to a basis of $W$ (which is essentially proving a special case of the rank-nullity theorem).

Comment: well if L is an isomorphism then V and W are isomorphic correct? And isn't there a theorem that states V and W are isomorphic if and only if dimV=dimW

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt Well, yes, but then why should you have an exercise asking to prove it?

Comment: I was just not aware that the definition of an inverse linear mapping stated that it was an isomorphism thats why I proved it so I could use the above theorem

Answer (score 0):

$dim V = n$

Given that $L$ is invertible, that means that $ \dim N(L) = 0$, and $\dim Im(L) = n$.

$L^{-1}$ is the inverse of $L$. $L^{-1}: W \rightarrow V$. $L^{-1}$ is injective and surjective, given that $L$ is invertible. That means $\dim N(L^{-1}) = 0$.

It also means that for every $x$ in $V$ there exists $y$ in $W$ such that $L^{-1}(y) = x$. Given that $\dim V = n$, it follows that $Im(L^{-1}) = n$, which proves that $\dim V = \dim W$.